# Can $interval's time parameter be dynamically changed between intervals?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm polling for upload progress of [sometimes large] entities. Within the first minute, I can be chatty with my upload service for status updates, but after the first minute, I can afford to ask less often.

Must i destroy the existing $interval and create a new one with a longer interval time value? or can I update the existing $interval's time parameter somehow?

Comment: In that case you should go with $timeout...

Comment: i'm running a specific call once per second. thats a perfect use case for $interval. but if i determine at some point that this interval may end up running for an hour, and not 5 minutes, then I dont need to be as chatty with my backend. why would I instantiate a new timeout over and over again just to emulate $interval?

Comment: What is your concern here? Is this a micro-optimization? It shouldn't be that costly to use a self-restarting $timeout or to stop an $interval and start a new one with a new time value.

Comment: @Kristian `can I update the existing $interval's time parameter somehow?` --> Which is not possible, what you are passing is a primitive number. `Must i destroy the existing $interval and create a new one with a longer interval time value` --> How is it better than just creating a timeout (unless you are not doing this very often)?

Comment: because i'm not doing this very often. i'm going run the call about 500 times... and i only need to update the interval time once after some threshold is met. lol. its OK guys, i have my answer now -- just destroy and instantiate  new interval...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options. I saw in the comments a suggestion for using settimeout which you might try. I have another suggestion it is possible to clear an interval and set another one. Code:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){alert('test');}, 3000);
```

Here is the other half:

```
<input type='button' value='test' onclick='clearTheInterval()'>

function clearTheInterval()
{
window.clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Then you can have some script to set the interval again. Tell me if this code doesn't work and I will come back and fix it because I'm on the phone right now.

Comment: this isn't technically correct since you're not using angular's $interval method, which is what the question was about. but the gist of it is correct. thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular js. I don't think it was mentioned in the question. Could you explain to me what angular js is?